# How could I count all the genres in my DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame called df_imdb:

[image]

Each row contains the information about a movie, This DataFrame has a column name 'genres' that shows the genre of that movie that could have more than one genre e.g. `[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}]`

I want to find out what are the most genre used in this movies (find the top 3 most used genres in this DataFrame)

Comment: Have you tried something like: `df['genres'].explode()['name'].value_counts()` ?

Comment: I tried it now, but it didn't work!!, Gave this error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode', actually, the type of the rows e.g. `type(df_imdb.loc[2,'genres'])` is **str**

Comment: Please don't post images. Instead paste everything as text. Also, post sample input data with expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is a list of dictionaries, multiple options here:

Option 1: Pure pandas, convert the values associated with key `name` to a `Series` and use `value_counts`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'genres':[[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}],[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 30, 'name': 'Blah'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}]]})

df['genres'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i['name'] for i in x]))\
.stack().value_counts()
```

You get

```
Thriller    2
Mystery     2
Action      1
Blah        1
```

Option 2: Convert the values to list and use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
l_genres = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x]).sum()
Counter(l_genres)
```

You get

```
Counter({'Thriller': 2, 'Action': 1, 'Mystery': 2, 'Blah': 1})
```

df['genres'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i['name'] for i in x])).stack().value_counts()

Edit: Data type is str and not list, first use `literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(literal_eval)
```

Comment: Actually, the type of the rows e.g. `type(df_imdb.loc[2,'genres']) ` is **str**

Comment: @MohammadPeighambari, pl see the edit. You need to first use literal_eval

Comment: Thanks for the update, It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
c = df_imbd['genres'].apply(lambda x: [n['name'] for n in x]).sum()
pd.Series(c).value_counts()
```

Comment: Gave this error: **string indices must be integers**

Comment: It works, can you try it again? Vaishali's answer is also quite similar and you confirmed.

Comment: yes dear, if you add this part: `from ast import literal_eval`

`df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(literal_eval)` your code will work as well. update your code and i will confirm it.

Comment: No, it's Vaishali's answer. I assumed it is a `list` (as you specified) but it is not so you should have clarified this in a more accurate way.

Comment: Sorry, My bad. I should have updated the question. But eventually, I mixed up both ways. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: I am happy that it helped.